# creme brulee caramelized sugar disappearing

Tags: caramelization, creme-brulee

I've recently made some creme brulee, poured sugar on top of it and used a kitchen blow torch to caramelize it and capitalise on a finished product.

After that I put the creme brulee in the fridge overnight and when I checked on it in the morning the caramel (caramelised sugar) had disappeared, leaving only a brown trace behind.

I *suppose* it got dissolved into the creme or underwent some sort of change and it wasn't a hard caramel layer anymore but I wanted to ask for a more experienced user's opinion.

I should also mention that particular batch had less cream in it that it should and it turned out more egg-y.

The precise recipe was:
3 medium egg yolks
200ml whipping cream
80g sugar

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. Creme brulee exudes and condensates enough moisture that the caramel would disappear. If you want to make it ahead, you have to make the custard only. Caramelization is always done just before serving.

Comment: I thought so but none of the recipes I looked at specified that, thanks for clarifying!

Comment: Not strictly always - it is possible to freeze a newly made caramel (once it cools) and allow it to defrost when you need it. Needs experience, but valuable when ten minutes just before the meal is more valuable than 40 some days before.